# Measuring the length of string containing wide characters

Tags: c#, silverlight, unicode, split

I have the following string:

```
友又
```

The corresponding UTF-16 representation (little-endian) is

```
CB 53 40 D8 87 DC C8 53
\___/ \_________/ \___/
  友              又
```

`"友又".Length` returns 4, because the string is stored as 4 2-byte characters by the CLR.

How do I measure the length of my string? How do I split it into `{ "友", "", "又" }`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx):

> The `Length` property returns the number of `Char` objects in this instance, not the number of Unicode characters. The reason is that a Unicode character might be represented by more than one `Char`. Use the [`System.Globalization.StringInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.aspx) class to work with each Unicode character instead of each Char.

---

Getting length:

```
new System.Globalization.StringInfo("友又").LengthInTextElements
```

---

Getting each Unicode character is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2f3k4f6.aspx), but it's much more convenient to make an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> TextElements(this string s) {
    var en = System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);

    while (en.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return en.GetTextElement();
    }
}
```

and use it in a `foreach` or in a LINQ statement:

```
foreach (string segment in "友又".TextElements())
{
    Console.WriteLine(segment);
}
```

which also can be used for length:

```
Console.WriteLine("友又".TextElements().Count());
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot. Would I use `GetTextElementEnumerator` to split the string?

Comment: @Clément Yes, you would, as [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2f3k4f6.aspx).