# How can I convert a unicode string like this U+1F61A to 0x1F600

Tags: c#, unicode, emoji

My code goes as such

```
    private IEnumerable<int> CombineSurrogates(string value)
    {
        if (null == value)
        {
            yield break; // or throw new ArgumentNullException(name(value));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
        {
            char current = value[i];
            char next = i < value.Length - 1 ? value[i + 1] : '\0';

            if (char.IsSurrogatePair(current, next))
            {
                yield return char.ConvertToUtf32(current, next);

                i += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return current;
            }
        }
    }

    private string DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters(string value)
    {
        return string.Join(" ", CombineSurrogates(value).Select(code => $"U+{code:X4}"));
    }
    string dn = DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters("");
    Console.WriteLine(dn);
```

it returns U+1F61A so I want help writing a function of turning U+1F61A to 0x1F600. So I can do this for other emojis I have available.

Because I am using a third party dll called NetUnicodeInfo to get the name of the emoji.

```
private string PrintCodePointInfo(int codePoint)
    {
        var charInfo = UnicodeInfo.GetCharInfo(codePoint);
        return charInfo.Name ?? charInfo.OldName;
    }
    PrintCodePointInfo(0x1F600);
```

because the codePoint is a int that's why i need to convert U+1F61A to 0x1F600.

Comment: .NET handles Surrogate Pairs for you already. What are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: I also don't see how the fact that `codePoint` is a `int` makes you need to convert 1F61A to 1F600. Both values are within the `int` range. Are you trying to re-invent [`TextElementEnumerator`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14115540/11683)?

Answer (score -1):

You should just do

```
return string.Join(" ", CombineSurrogates(value).Select(code => $"0x{code:X4}"));
```

Reference: [The Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString).